# How to move multiple elements from one list to another and delete from first list

Tags: python, list

I would like to move elements from one list to another based on a separate boolean list.
I attempted the following pattern but pop at an early index shortens the list and I run into an IndexError at later elements.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = []
to_move = [True, False, False, True]

for idx, element in enumerate(to_move):
  if element:
    list_2.append(list_1.pop[idx]) #at element 4 (index 3), list_1 has already had its indices changed and cannot pop based on index 3
```

Another way might be to remove elements AFTER initial move, but I currently run into the same problem.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list_2 = []
to_move = [True, False, False, True]

for idx, element in enumerate(to_move):
  if element:
    list_2.append(list_1[idx])
for idx, element in enumerate(to_move):
  if element:
     list_1.remove(idx) # is there a way to remove all elements at once based on index?
```

If there is a way to move/remove all elements in a list at once (ie. without losing index spot in list), thus avoiding an IndexError?

Comment: Have you considered removing items from the list starting from the end of the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't try to modify a list as you're iterating over it, as the memory is shifting while you're trying to access it (the mapping between the elements in `list_1` and `to_move` may not be easily retained if you remove elements from `list_1` as well).

Instead, use a list comprehension:

```py
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
to_move = [True, False, False, True]

list_2 = [elem for index, elem in enumerate(list_1) if to_move[index]]
list_1 = [elem for index, elem in enumerate(list_1) if not to_move[index]]

print(list_1, list_2) # Prints [2, 3] [1, 4]
```

Comment: Just in case you need to retain the original `list_1` object (maybe you are trying to remove items in-place from a function argument), do a slice assignment: `list_1[:] = [...]`.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you both!